# Azure blobs backup

Tags: azure, backup, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azcopy

We use some

- block blobs to store some durable resources and then
- page blobs to store event data

**We need to backup the blobs, so I tried to use AzCopy**. It works ok on my dev machine, but it fails on other slow machine with error "*The remote server returned an error: (412) The condition specified using HTTP conditional header(s) is not met..*" almost every time.
We write to page blobs quite often (might be **up** to several times in a second, but this is not so common case), so this might be the reason.

Is there any better strategy how to backup the changing blobs? Or is there any way how to bypass the problem with ETag used by AzCopy?

Comment: A few questions: 1) Do you get this error only with Page Blobs or does this happen with Block Blobs as well? 2) Are you copying the blobs in the same storage account or across storage accounts?

Comment: Ad 1. Just with page blobs (that get frequent update), Ad 2. Same storage. I already learned that copying to other storage takes much more time.

Comment: Please look at David's answer below. I believe taking a blob snapshot and using that for copying will solve your problem. The question is how you would do that using AzCopy. I think you will need to resort to PowerShell where for each Page Blob you would take a snapshot first and then copy using that snapshot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A changed ETag will always halt a copy, since a changing ETag signifies that the source has changed.

The general approach to blob backup is subjective, but objectively:

- blob copies within Azure itself, in the same region, from Storage account to Storage account, are going to be significantly faster than trying to copy a blob to an on-premises location (due to general Internet latency) or even copying from storage account to local disk on a VM.
- Blobs support snapshots (which take place relatively instantly). If you create a snapshot, the snapshot remains unchanged, allowing you to then execute a copy operation against the *snapshot* instead of the actual blob itself (using AzCopy in your case) without fear of the source data changing during the copy. *Note: You can create as many snapshots as you want; just be careful, since storage size grows as the underlying original blob changes*.

Comment: +1, One method is to use blob snapshots, and the Snapshot Blob operation creates a read-only snapshot of a blob, more information about blob snapshots, refer to the link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/fileservices/Snapshot-Blob?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: If I understand it correctly, I should make a snapshot from the page blob and then copy the snapshot to the backup location as a new page blob. After that I can delete the snapshot, right?

Comment: Is there any tool that can work with snapshots? List them and copy them? Or at least PowerShell commandlets?

Comment: @stej - this is all documented, and plenty of examples are around for using AzCopy/PowerShell/SDKs with snapshots. I suggest reading up on the docs/examples to see specifics.

Comment: Honestly, I haven't found "plenty" of examples. I need to copy the snapshot, not the blob itself. E.g. https://learn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/azure/storage/storage-use-azcopy#azcopy-parameters is only about copying blob + snapshot together. Anyway, the answer is "snapshots", so I'll accept your response. Thank you.

Comment: For othes there is some info about PowerShell & snapshots in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-powershell-guide-full